# PHP MySQL query problem with string despite using mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

The following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`param1`, `param2`) 
VALUES (
'Новости Томска – подборка новостей из общественной жизни города, политики, спорта, обзор происшествий, событий.\r\nПолезная информация о недвижимости, авто, финансах, работе и консультации специалистов.\r\nОбъявления по различным тематикам, вакансии томских работодателей. \', 
'Томский городской портал, Томск, Портал города Томска, Недвижимость в Томске, Авторынок Томска, Продажа авто в Томске, Работа в Томске, Вакансии, Резюме, Отдых в Томске, Афиша Томска, Новости Томска, Томский форум, Погода в Томске, Томские сайты, Каталог томских сайтов, Частны');
```

failed with error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'Томский
>   городской портал, Томск, Портал гор'
>   at line 1

I have used mysql_real_escape_string on the strings before using them on the SQL query, so I thought this was enough to make them error-free.

My database is set to use

> utf8_general_ci

as Collation for these fields.

What can be the problem with the query?

Comment: why not to post here full code? I see no reason to get such error from PHP code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are escaping the `'` that should close the value of param1 (the first value in the `values` clause) :

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`param1`, `param2`) 
VALUES (
'...й. \',   <= there
'...ны');
```

You should **remove the `\` before the closing `'`**, so your query looks like this :

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`param1`, `param2`) 
VALUES (
'...й. ', 
'...ны');
```

The `\` is necessary to escape quotes inside the strings -- and not quotes that are string delimiters.

Comment: Thanks!  Is the PHP function stripslashes the way to best way to "clean" the string before using it for a MySQL query?

Comment: No : you should use the escaping function that corresponds to your database driver -- mysql_real_escape_string if you're working with mysql_* function. But you must escape each string separately.